# Why doesn't a member function change my objects data members?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

So I was working on a Project for a computer science class in which we need to create a binary search tree and a corresponding index. We needed to use recursion for this project.

Here is my class implementation:

```
class Leaf;
struct indexEntries;
class BinarySearchTree{
    public:
        BinarySearchTree();
        ~BinarySearchTree();

        //Helper Functions for recursive calls
        std::string search(std::string);
        void BuildTree(std::string);
        void inOrderPrint();

    private:
        //Recursive Functions
        void BuildTreeR(int start, int end, Leaf * r);
        void inOrderPrint(Leaf * start);
        Leaf * search(std::string inquiry, Leaf * start);
        void DeallocateTree(Leaf * start);

        //Data members
        Leaf * root;
        std::vector<indexEntries> BSTindex;     
};


class Leaf{
    public:
        Leaf(){
            indexID = "";
            AccNum = "";
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
        };
        void set_index(std::string input)      {indexID = input;};
        void set_AccNum(std::string input)     {AccNum = input;};
        void set_left(Leaf* newLeft)   {left = newLeft;};
        void set_right(Leaf* newRight) {right = newRight;};
        std::string get_index()    {return indexID;};
        std::string get_AccNum()   {return AccNum;};
        Leaf * get_left()  {return left;};
        Leaf * get_right() {return right;};

    private:
        std::string indexID;
        std::string AccNum;
        Leaf * left;
        Leaf * right;
};
```

And when I try to pass `Leaf * BinarySearchTree::root` to the function void `BinarySearchTree::BuildTreeR(int, int, Leaf*)` the Leaf that the root is pointing to goes unchanged.

Here is my BuildTreeR() function:

```
void BinarySearchTree::BuildTreeR(int start, int end, Leaf * parent){
    int mid = (start+end)/2;
    if(parent == NULL){
        parent = new Leaf;
        parent->set_index((BSTindex[mid]).indexID);
        std::string fullEntry = BSTindex[mid].dataBaseEntry;
        parent->set_AccNum(fullEntry.substr(4, 3));
    }

    if((mid-1)>start){
        BuildTreeR(start, mid-1, parent->get_left());
    }
     if((mid+1)<end){
        BuildTreeR(mid+1, end, parent->get_right());
    }
}
```

Using the debugger, I found that the leaf pointed to by Leaf * parent gets changed, but these changes are not carried over to `Leaf * BinarySearchTree::root`, which stops my program from working.

The debugger says that the value of the data I'm trying to change is

```
CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
```

Has anyone had this happen before/ know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis of the problem is exactly right: the pointer is passed by value, so any changes that the function makes to the value of `parent` are not visible to the caller.

One way to fix the problem is by passing the `parent` pointer by reference:

```
void BinarySearchTree::BuildTreeR(int start, int end, Leaf *& parent){
```

(note the added `&`).

This way any changes made to `parent` inside the function will automatically be visible to the caller.

Comment: I had tried that last night, before the project was due. Editing it in both the implementation and the header file, but I still had the same error for all of the data I was attempting to change.

Comment: I attempted to use this again and now it wont compile saying `'BinarySearchTree::BuildTreeR' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'Leaf *' to 'Leaf *&'`

Comment: @mcnnowak: You also need to change `get_left()` and `get_right()` to return a reference to pointer (or a pointer to pointer).